# is it normal to have different md5 for apache maven

Tags: macos, apache, security, maven, md5

I am downloading apache marven form this official website

https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

I downloaded    `apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.tar.gz` and calculated the md5 and the result is  `9f0fa573a526785b8e0adb0631687ad5` while the result on the official page is: `794b3b7961200c542a7292682d21ba36`

** is that normal? **

then i downloaded apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.zip and for some reason, my mac 10.10.1 gives me a folder after finishing downloading not a zip file

i am worried about the security of that file since there are two different md5 results, is that normal please?

Comment: how did you calculate md5 of downloaded tarball ?

Comment: using md5 in terminal in mac os . the answer bellow helps me, the solution was to download the second one, because the first one still gives different md5.

Comment: which one gives you different md5 could you please add link to downloadable in question and expected md5 and md5 you are getting

Comment: First downloading in Mac and getting a folder is usual behaviour cause Mac downloads and creates a decompressed folder of it...but you can select that and change. Getting the wrong checksum sounds weird...cause i've checked and get the correct one `794b3b7961200c542a7292682d21ba36`. I assume your download has not been finished. Have you tried to do the download via curl / wget  instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file must have been corrupted during download. You have to download it again. That is of course assuming you are certain the md5 hash corresponds to that file.

A cryptographic hash of a given piece of data is unique. **You cannot have two different hashes for the same piece of data**. However,  you could have the same hash for two different pieces of data, although that is quite unlikely. That is called a hash collision.

Comment: I did try to download it many times and i got always a different md5, did you try it yourself please? what do you suggest? can I install it?

Comment: I assume you get a different md5 after each download. I mean that you do not get the same md5 on two different downloads, or do you?

Comment: the same md5 every time, the same wrong md5 every time

Comment: what is the solution now please? i badly need to install marven

Comment: "my mac 10.10.1 gives me a folder after finishing downloading not a zip file" : You browser downloads and opens the zip file. You need to right click on the link and select download or the like.

Comment: You could also consider using a download manager. Also make sure you are correctly cakculating the md5.

Comment: but that doesn't mean the problem is solved :), because `apache-maven-3.2.5-bin.tar.gz` still gives wrong md5, however, ` apache-maven-3.2.5-bin.zip` works will

Comment: If you are consistently getting the same wrong md5 after each dowt of the gz file that could indicate that your download is somehow interrupted at the same spot at each download or that the posted md5 is not correct.  You might just want to move on and get your job done. :-)

Comment: Try with curl or wget instead of your browser.